# Newly planted grass is yellowish-green, how to fix?

Tags: grass, discoloration

A contractor planted grass seed last year and it looks IMO horrible now. It is a yellowish green color and the blades of the grass are thicker, making it seem out of place compared to the other surrounding grass which has smaller/finer blades. Is there any way to correct this or should I rip it out and re-seed? Before winter, I tried adding my Scott's northeast blend, which is why you see hints of darker green in some spots.

New grass on the left:

[image: New grass on the left]

Close up:

[image]

Comment: Doesn’t help now, but - I would avoid that contractor in the future if they think they can just plant any old grass seed in an established lawn without first checking with you what seed to plant.

Comment: But, if it were me, I would rip it out or kill it and start over. I don’t think there is any other way :(